# How can I correctly add controls into a MDI Parent?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mdi

I'm setting up my main form as a MDI Parent in order to include some forms that I've designed.

I have no problem with this part.

My problem comes when I try to add 'generic controls'. I mean... I need to add some controls directly into the main form (the MDI container), like a status bar, some logos, labels... etc. I know I can add it but it appears floating over the child forms. What I want to do is to create an area on the bottom of my form, so the MDI Container size adjusts by itself.

Probably I'm not a good speaker, so here you have an image, for clarifying my poor explanation:

http://es.tinypic.com/r/2h391qw/9

I need something that integrates well, on the same way that 'menuStrip' does.

Also sorry for my english, I know it's not precisely the best...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure with the tags? Doing this in C++CLI seams strange to me.

Comment: You must use a container for these controls, like a Panel, and set its Dock property to one of the edges of the parent.  That shrinks the mdi client window, the dark gray one that is the parent for any mdi child window.

Comment: @xMRi yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know that a Panel could be setted up as a MDI container... That's a good way. Finally I used the main form as MDI parent and added a 'splitter' to it, so the MDI container zone resized as expected. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to create an outer frame, containing the MDI client window and additional windows like status bar etc. When the frame is resized it resizes all other windows in it.

Usually the MDI Parent window is never used for user controls. I suppose that this will never work

Comment: Yes, it works. I've used this method too many times and there's no problem. What kind of control do you mean when you talk about 'frame'? Thank you,

Comment: Create a Outer Form (the frame, create a new window inside the first, this gets the MDIParent.